# Show button only if last page was a specific one

Tags: javascript, hide, visibility, show

I try to only display a button if the last one was a specific one, see my code:

```js
var oldURL = document.referrer;
var sitename = "admin_tool.html";
var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
if (oldURL === sitename) {
  x.style.visibility = "visible"
} else {
  x.style.visibility = "hidden"
}
```

but its not working for me... 
Any help is highly appreciated !
Thanks alot guys!

Comment: Check the content of `document.referrer`

Comment: in if condition try this `oldURL && (oldURL.indexOf(sitename) != -1`.

Comment: The `document.referrer` value is not reliable. It can be spoofed and in some situations it's not set by the browser at all.

Comment: @AagamJain did not help... However thanks for the answer anyway !

Comment: what alternative could I use if document.referrer isnt reliable ? any ideas ?

Comment: @Andreas I checked it and it says: "Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade"

Comment: if you are coming from your own site or page add some `cookie` or `localStorage` values and read it one current page.

Comment: if I type "javascript:alert(document.referrer)" in console I just get a empty window/alert

Comment: I found the problem, when I just started my app from a local place on my harddrive the browser cant get a document.refferer. Than I set up a xampp apache localhost server and now the browser can get the document.referrer and the script works !